# How does speculative execution impact s3-dist-cp job?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, s3distcp

I have noticed that sometimes s3-dist-cp takes much longer than usual due to a "slow node" issue. In case of spark I have enabled speculative execution which works fine. Howerver, when it comes to s3-dist-cp I would like to understand possible impact first.

In case of regular dist-cp I found that (link: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html#MapReduce_and_other_side-effects):

```
If mapreduce.map.speculative is set set final and true, the result of the copy is undefined.
```

I'm aware that s3-dist-cp is a completely separate job, but I wonder if there any caveats. I wasn't able to find any related documentation.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: So what is the question then in fact?

Comment: Are you running many jobs at the same time with s3DistCP?

Comment: I would look at the hadoop source rather than ask anyone on stack overflow whose opinions will only be second hand (other user) or, if they wrote bits of distcp, probably out of date. Note that s3-distcp isn't open source, so look at `distcp -direct  -numListstatusThreads 40` for cloud perf

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that `mapreduce.reduce.speculative` is programatically set to `false`. Even if you specify `-Dmapreduce.reduce.speculative=true`, it is ignored.

Comment: @stevel never underestimate others

Comment: @thebluephantom maybe, but despite being someone who maintains distcp. even I wouldn't make any assertions without reviewing the code to see what the latest behaviour is. And stack overflow answers get out of date so fast...

Comment: @stevel point taken